# ¿Como eliminar scroll que aparece al mostrar una tabla dentro de un accordion de Jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatables

saludos.

Si se fijan cuando hacemos click en table1 se muestra una tabla y eso todo bien. Pero si se fijan despues de mostrar la tabla se genera un espacio no agradable(despues de la paginacion) y ese espacion aparece hasta donde se muestra el segundo acordion.

Y cuando damos click en table2 no se genera dicho espacio despues de la paginacion, espero me entiendan.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
  $('#MyTable2').DataTable();

});



$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: false });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3 class="text-center">Table 1</h3>
  <div>
    <table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$725,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$237,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Development Lead</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fiona Green</td>
          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shou Itou</td>
          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
          <td>Team Leader</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
          <td>Post-Sales support</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$324,050</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Unity Butler</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$85,675</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$164,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
          <td>Secretary</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$109,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$452,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$136,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$645,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Olivia Liang</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$234,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$163,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$139,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Thor Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$98,540</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$87,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$138,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$125,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
          <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lael Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2010/07/14</td>
          <td>$86,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shad Decker</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/11/13</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>Customer Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h3 class="text-center">Table 2</h3>
  <div>
    <table id="myTable2" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Support Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Charde Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$470,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$725,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$237,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Development Lead</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fiona Green</td>
          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shou Itou</td>
          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
          <td>Team Leader</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
          <td>Post-Sales support</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$324,050</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Unity Butler</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$85,675</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$164,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
          <td>Secretary</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$109,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$452,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$136,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$645,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Olivia Liang</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$234,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$163,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$139,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Thor Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$98,540</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$87,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$138,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$125,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
          <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lael Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola agrega el atributo `heightStyle: "content"` [JQueryUI auto-height](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
  $('#MyTable2').DataTable();

});



$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", heightStyle: "content", collapsible: true, active: false });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3 class="text-center">Table 1</h3>
  <div>
    <table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$725,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$237,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Development Lead</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fiona Green</td>
          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shou Itou</td>
          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
          <td>Team Leader</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
          <td>Post-Sales support</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$324,050</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Unity Butler</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$85,675</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$164,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
          <td>Secretary</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$109,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$452,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$136,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$645,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Olivia Liang</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$234,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$163,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$139,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Thor Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$98,540</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$87,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$138,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$125,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
          <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lael Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2010/07/14</td>
          <td>$86,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shad Decker</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/11/13</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>Customer Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h3 class="text-center">Table 2</h3>
  <div>
    <table id="myTable2" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Support Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Charde Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$470,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$725,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$237,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Development Lead</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fiona Green</td>
          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shou Itou</td>
          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
          <td>Team Leader</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
          <td>Post-Sales support</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$324,050</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Unity Butler</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$85,675</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$164,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
          <td>Secretary</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$109,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$452,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$136,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$645,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Olivia Liang</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$234,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$163,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$139,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Thor Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$98,540</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$87,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$138,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$125,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
          <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lael Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciona, gracias.